# CNN regression. help to improve current model

Tags: time-series, regression, cnn, image-recognition

I have time series grey scale images that show movement of fluid with different densities.
I want to predict a pixel value for time t, with (t-3),(t-2),(t-1) 2D images as inputs.

I am figuring out how to use what layers.
This is my current basic configuration. I believe this can be vastly improved.

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(16, (3,3), padding="same", activation='relu'), input_shape=training_input_nparray[0].shape))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding="same", activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding="same", activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(GlobalAveragePooling2D()))
model.add(LSTM(1024, activation='relu', return_sequences=False))

model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile('adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Training input array and output array shapes:
(1785, 3, 180, 206, 1)
(1785, 1)